# Postgresql on OpenShift 2, using node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, postgresql, openshift

I have an app that uses Node.js and Postgresql on OpenShift, I can connect locally to the database and make queries, but I can't get it to work on the openshift server.  When I push to server, I get this error:

Waiting for application port (8080) become available ...
Application 'myapp' failed to start (port 8080 not available)
But Im using the port 8080...

My openshift ports are:

> Service  --- Local  ---------------  OpenShift
>
> node ------ 127.0.0.1:8080  =>  127.8.120.129:8080
>
> postgresql 127.0.0.1:5432  =>  127.8.120.130:5432

And here I write the important code line. 
First, the **server.js**:

```
...
var db = require('./postgresql/database.js');
db.sync();
...
var server_port = process.env.OPENSHIFT_NODEJS_PORT || 8080
var server_ip_address = process.env.OPENSHIFT_NODEJS_IP || '127.0.0.1'
server.listen(server_port, server_ip_address, function () {});
...
```

And **database.js**:

```
var Sequelize = require('sequelize');
var bd_url = process.env.OPENSHIFT_POSTGRESQL_DB_URL || 'postgres://'user':'pass'@127.0.0.1:5432/sw'
var sequelize = new Sequelize(bd_url, {
    dialect: 'postgres',
    dialectOptions: {}
});
module.exports = sequelize;
```

Does anyone know what can fail?

Thanks!

Comment: What version of OpenShift are you using and where is it running?

Comment: OpenShift v2 and Postgresql 9.2, I forgot to say it, Im using eclipse

Answer (score 0):

OpenShift provides a default web server (written in Ruby) on almost every container/cartridge you create.

Every service is started using the "***start***" service hook, located at:

**$OPENSHIFT_REPO_DIR/.openshift/action_hooks/start**

You may find a line like this one:

```
[]\> nohup $OPENSHIFT_REPO_DIR/diy/testrubyserver.rb $OPENSHIFT_DIY_IP $OPENSHIFT_REPO_DIR/diy |& /usr/bin/logshifter -tag diy &
```

In order to verify which application is using port 8080, you can execute "**oo-lists-ports**" command.

This command is just an alias for "**lsof**" command.

Execute it without any arguments and you'll obtain the application that it's locking your port 8080 (in my case):

```
[]\> oo-lists-ports
COMMAND   PID     USER   FD   TYPE DEVICE SIZE/OFF NODE NAME
node    88451     1027   10u  IPv4 392176      0t0  TCP 127.2.1.129:8080 (LISTEN)
[]\>
```

With the above information (PID), you just need to kill the related process:
(in my case)

```
[]\> ps -ef |grep 88451
1027      62829  61960  0 08:33 pts/0    00:00:00 grep 88451
1027      88451      1  0 Jun21 ?        00:00:16 node faceBot.js

[]\> kill -9 88451
```

After killing the process that is locking your port 8080 you will be able to run your Node JS stack on that port.

Regards

Comment: Thanks, but I think its an error on the code of postgresql, if I comment that line (the conexion to postgresql): 
`//var db = require('./postgresql/database.js');`
`//db.sync();`
I havent any problem.